# Need to format table in MVC view to generate PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, formatting, html-table, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf and this is my view that generates that PDF, however for some reason the styling and formatting isn't working. I have tried to align text and add css styling but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have some advice on how I can get the table to display the top row to be one line of information instead of getting cut off and moved under. Here is what the PDF curently looks like; as you can see the row doesn't look right. I need that row to be one single line flowing together. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is my MVC view that is generating the PDF:

```
@model List<ArdentMC.DHS.COP.Mobile.MVC.Models.Reports>
@{
Layout = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="color:red; align:center;">UNCLASSIFIED/FOR OFFICAL USE ONLY</div>

<table style="width:300px;"> 

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
<td> @item.Phase </td>
<td> @item.NocNumber</td>
<td> @item.Title</td>
<td> @item.Location</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
       <td>@item.ReportDateText</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>  
 @foreach (var item in Model){
     @Html.Raw(item.Description)
 }
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
     <div style="color:black; align:center;">US Department of Homeland Security</div>
        <br />
        <div style="color:red; align:center;">UNCLASSIFIED/FOR OFFICAL USE ONLY</div>   
     </body>
  </html>
```